# Build Servers, build agents, com registration and Windows 7 permissions

Tags: com, registration, msbuild-task

I am trying to build a continuous integration server on a Windows 7 machine. I can run the msbuild script cleanly on that machine but when I attempt to run it via a build agent the registration of certain COM (.NET and c++) components fail seemingly to do with write permissions to the registry. I have turned off UAC but it makes no difference. Normally if I build the msbuild script locally I have to run the command prompt with elevated permissions, but on a build server I am not sure what to do.

I have seen posts suggesting that the way is to remove the automatic registration from the project setup, and rely on the install to do this. This seems to make it this option rather limited and the solution incompatible with running from an IDE. Has anyone found a way through this?

We are using vs2010 as the client on the build server, and the TFS server is vs2008

Comment: I'm having the same kind of problem. I've added the build service user account to a local computer group which in turn has full rights on the 'classes' sections of the registry for the local machine, which worked fine on our old TFS2008 build server, but doesn't on the new TFS2010 one. :( By removing the COMVisible attribute from the project's assembly info file, it gets past that, but a similar issue arises in the InstallShield packaging, where InstallShield is unable to get at the COM info for the DLL.

Comment: Don't register COM components on a build server.  That's only necessary for executing them, not for building them.

Answer (score 0):

Add your build service user into Administrators user group. It seems like your account has more permissions as build agent/service user.